# Convert Mdb to Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

How can i convert mdb access file to sql server using c# or other languages?
I found an [article](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/234266-Convert-MS-Access-DB-to-MS-SQL-w-Visual-Studio/) in msdn. But, i couldnt understand.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your SQL Server database and then use Integration Services to transform the data. It makes sense to review the database design thoroughly before doing this. A design made for Jet won't necessarily be the best one for SQL Server.

EDIT: I failed to mention one other significant difference. Jet/ACE enforces nullable foreign keys when a null is inserted, whereas SQL Server follows the SQL standard which requires that nulls are ignored in foreign key constraints (the constraint isn't violated). If you have nullable foreign keys then I highly recommend you redesign so that you can make them non-nullable in SQL Server (by moving the column(s) to a new table for example).

Comment: @dportas: You posted this answer twice? I'm assuming you didn't actually mean to do this?

Comment: Please explain in more detail how a design created in Jet isn't the best for SQL Server.

Comment: To reinforce Tony's question, other than data types, I can't see that a Jet/ACE schema should not work just fine in SQL Server. Sure, SQL Server has triggers and only A2010 has them, but I think triggers are not necessarily a good thing (depends on what they are used for). I can't see how a simpler schema could be a problem if it's implemented in Jet/ACE, even if it can't use some of the more advanced features that SQL Server might offer.

Comment: Jet when used in conjunction with Access permits things that are sensitive to record ordering in a table. E.g. DLOOKUP, FIRST and LAST functions. If you rely on row ordering then you may need to add extra columns to your SQL Server table to represent that ordering, if the order isn't already recorded explicitly. Jet also allows updating of individual rows in tables without keys. So it's possible (however undesirable) to use keyless tables. In SQL Server that's unlikely to be feasible in any reliable, predictable way. For most practical purposes those tables will need keys in SQL Server.

Comment: So, you're saying that a schema designed with mistakes in it won't work well in SQL Server? Isn't that true in both directions? DLookup() is not a Jet/ACE SQL function (or, at least, has no place there, even if it can be used via the Jet/ACE expression service), and First and Last are meaningless without an ORDER BY. Using DLookup in SQL or using First/Last without an ORDER BY is pilot error, not something wrong with the Jet/ACE schema. Pilot error is possible when using any database engine.

Comment: It probably is true "in both directions" but this question is about migration from Access to SQL Server. If your database design uses keyless tables or assumes order-sensitive code can be used then those designs are likely to fail in SQL Server. Similarly perhaps for "lookup" fields and "relationships" - features which have no direct equivalents in SQL Server. It really doesn't matter whether these are part of Jet or not. People can and do rely on them and base their Jet database designs around them and therefore they may need to rethink when migrating to another platform.

Comment: I don't know anybody who would have the competence to migrate a Jet/ACE database to SQL Server who would rely on any of those things. In short, you've created a straw man in order to insult Access. Downvoting accordingly.

Comment: I "insulted" Access how? You are absurd. I mentioned those differences between Jet and SQL Server because I have a number of times answered questions from users who wanted to migrate those features from Jet/Access to SQL Server. The person doing the migration isn't necessarily the one who created the MDB. As I think you know, there are a great many Access users without much knowledge or experience of database design. Clearly you have your own agenda which has nothing to do with the genuine needs of the Access community.

Comment: Hakan: I failed to mention one other significant difference. Jet/ACE enforces nullable foreign keys when a null is inserted, whereas SQL Server follows the SQL standard which requires that nulls are ignored in foreign key constraints (the constraint isn't violated). If you have nullable foreign keys then I highly recommend you redesign so that you can make them non-nullable in SQL Server (by moving the column(s) to a new table for example).

Comment: Jet/ACE treats Nulls in FKs according to the way you've defined them. I really don't understand your point at all, except if I interpret it as being based on an incomplete understanding of RI in Jet/ACE.

Comment: You've still never answer Tony's question, really. All databases have non-overlapping feature sets, so somethings that you can implement in one cannot be exactly replicated in another. This is normal, and not a lack in any of the db engines involved (though I must say MySQL's original lack of foreign-key constraints gives me pause in making such a statement).

Comment: I think I've answered Tony's question with several examples. If you rely on the features I mentioned then you may need to revise your database design, add/change keys or make other alterations. No-one is talking about a "lack" in anything. I'm just saying they are different products and you can't necessarily expect exactly the same behaviour in each (something which you apparently now agree with). Therefore it is only prudent to review the design thoroughly to see if it will still meet your requirements after migration. I would say the same about migrating a database from SQL Server to Oracle.

Comment: @david @dportas you know, guys, you can discuss this without insulting each other or getting overly defensive of a particular rdbms.  I'm tempted to wipe the comments, but there's some good info in here.  Please, think of the infos.

Comment: I think the problem here is that @dportas is talking about Access features, while I'm talking about Jet/ACE features. It seems much more logical to discuss features of the database engine only, since migrating it to SQL Server will only ever involved the database engine end of the equation. @dportas'c objections seem to me to be completely inapplicable -- he's not addressing the actual scenario involved in the question (i.e., migrating from one database engine to another) because he's confusing Access the database application development tool with its default database engine, Jet/ACE.

Comment: I'm talking about changes that may be required when you migrate to SQLServer if you rely on certain features that work with Jet/ACE. I don't know why it would matter whether the features being used are part of Jet/ACE or not. The point is simply that changes may be required because SQL Server works differently to Jet/ACE. Among the examples I gave are that you can update individual rows without keys in Jet/ACE but that's unlikely to be feasible in SQL Server and that foreign keys in Jet work differently to SQL Server. According to you, stating these differences is "insulting"! Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

this is not at all something you could do with C# ( unless you really want to read the schema of access tables and create similar schema in SQL Server using ADO.NET commands ).

if your operation has to be done once only, it's much much easier you open SQL Management Studio, create an empty database and then right click on it, Tasks and "Import Data", then from the wizard you can select Import from MS Access and SQL Server will import structure and data.

This answer is not valid in case you really want to write tons of code in C# to "mimic" what the mentioned wizard does and have a generic tool to use with different databases...

Comment: i know it was late. i solve it. In fact, i have an iphone application. My think was, firstly mdb file was converted to sqlserver. Then, samely converted to mysql, then sqlite file. It was so long and silly way, i know. But, I used google mdb to sqlite code. Greatfull. Thanks for all.